# SOAP Request and Response using the same Element not showing in SoapUI

Tags: java, soap, soapui, spring-ws

When one usually creates a SOAP request and response element, it would end in __*Request and _*_Response and SoapUI would pick it up when you import the WSDL.

```
<xs:element name="SampleRequest">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Testing" type="xs:string" />  
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="SampleResponse">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Testing" type="xs:string" />  
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

I'm busy converting a piece of old VB6 code and the DTD's SOAP equivalent would use the same element for request and response:

```
<xs:element name="Sample">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Testing" type="xs:string" />  
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Is there something I can set in the XSD so that SOAPUI would pick up Sample as both a request and a response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When SOAPUI reads the WSDL, it uses the element (and therefore the element name) defined in the wsdl:message element which is referenced from the wsdl:operation element as the request, response, and optional fault.  Nothing you do to an XSD will change that.  Nor do elements have to end with "Request" to be considered a request (same for Response).

Comment: I'm using Spring-ws which auto-generates the WSDL, does that mean I need to manually add a Sample operation to the WSDL for SOAPUI to pick it up?

Comment: Is it possible to configure Spring-WS to include other wsdl:operations?

Comment: Every web server container I've used always generates the WSDL - even when you give it a WSDL.  (Put comments in your WSDL, then deploy, then fetch the WSDL from the container - the comments will most likely be gone.)  Containers do this to ensure the WSDL matches the deployed application, which is probably a good idea.

Comment: I know nothing of Spring-ws, but I'll assume it supports JSR 181 annotations.  If you annotate your method with @WebResult(name="SampleResponse") and your method arguments with @WebParam(name = "SampleRequest") then you'll get the element names you want.

Comment: I used a filter to intercept the WSDL before it is displayed, then just string-replaced the SampleRequest and SampleResponse with Sample and it works brilliantly.

Answer (score 0):

Solved it by replacing all SampleRequest and SampleResponse with just Sample and removing the now duplicate wsdl:message:

```
...


<wsdl:message name="Sample">
    <wsdl:part element="tns:Sample" name="Sample">
    </wsdl:part>
</wsdl:message>

<wsdl:portType name="SampleSoapService">
    <wsdl:operation name="Sample">
        <wsdl:input message="tns:Sample" name="Sample">
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output message="tns:Sample" name="Sample">
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:portType>

<wsdl:binding name="SampleSoapServiceSoap11" type="tns:SampleSoapService">
    <soap:binding style="document"
        transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Sample">
        <soap:operation soapAction="" />
        <wsdl:input name="Sample">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:input>
        <wsdl:output name="Sample">
            <soap:body use="literal" />
        </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
</wsdl:binding>
<wsdl:service name="SampleSoapServiceService">
    <wsdl:port binding="tns:SampleSoapServiceSoap11" name="SampleSoapServiceSoap11">
        <soap:address location="http://localhost:8080/paygate-SampleSoapService/ws/SampleSoapService" />
    </wsdl:port>
</wsdl:service>
```